# How to repair this query error

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error with the below query:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON posts.post_category_id=categories.category_id posts.post_author_id=admin.adm' at line 22`

How can I fix this?

```
SELECT
posts.post_id,
posts.post_title,
posts.post_img,
posts.post_content,
posts.post_content_m,
posts.post_author_id,
posts.post_keywords,
posts.post_category_id,
posts.post_img,
posts.post_date,
posts.post_time,
posts.post_hit,
posts.post_comment,
posts.post_status,
posts.post_trash,
categories.category_id,
categories.category_title,
admin.admin_id,
admin.admin_name
FROM posts  JOIN categories , admin
ON posts.post_category_id=categories.category_id  posts.post_author_id=admin.admin_id
WHERE posts.post_trash='0'
ORDER BY posts.post_id
```

Comment: Looks like you're mixing JOIN methods. One is designed to use JOIN and ON, the other uses a comma and a WHERE comparison. Here you're using ON for both JOIN and comma.

Comment: Thank you error fixed and problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT
posts.post_id,
posts.post_title,
posts.post_img,
posts.post_content,
posts.post_content_m,
posts.post_author_id,
posts.post_keywords,
posts.post_category_id,
posts.post_img,
posts.post_date,
posts.post_time,
posts.post_hit,
posts.post_comment,
posts.post_status,
posts.post_trash,
categories.category_id,
categories.category_title,
admin.admin_id,
admin.admin_name
FROM posts INNER JOIN categories
ON posts.post_category_id=categories.category_id  
INNER JOIN admin ON
posts.post_author_id=admin.admin_id
WHERE posts.post_trash='0'
ORDER BY posts.post_id  ";
```